# Could Not return multiple MySql Result

Tags: php, mysql

This is my query. And i am trying to return multiple values from the MySql result

```
function getName()
{
  $field_id=$_REQUEST['field_id'];

  for($i=0;$i<$_REQUEST['countLoc'];$i++)
  {
       $val=$_REQUEST['val_check'.trim($i)];

       $sql="UPDATE customer SET sub_ID=$field_id WHERE ff_custID='$val'";
       $rs=parent::_executeQuery($sql);
       $rs = parent::getAll($rs);

       $sql2="SELECT * FROM customer WHERE sub_ID='$field_id' AND ff_custID='$val'";
       $rs2=parent::_executeQuery($sql2);
       $rs2=parent::getAll($rs2); 

       $name = $rs2[0]['name'];
       echo $name;
  }
return $name;
}
```

SO the `echo $name` will show multiple names fetched from the result. And when i `return $name` is returning single result.

For suppose if

```
$name = $rs2[0]['name']; is showing 'David' and 'Mark' inside the loop,
the returned value i am   getting is only `David`
```

How do i return all the result fetched inside the loop

Comment: "SO the echo $name will show multiple names fetched from the result" I doubt it would be returning multiple names since you are using $rs2[0]['name'] instead of $rs2[i]['name'], aprt from that see my answer for why you are getting only one value during return

Answer (score 2, accepted):

your $name is storing only current value of name in every iteration as previous one is being replaced everytime, so when you return, only last instance is being returned.
so try something like this :
before for loop set

```
$name =''
```

in for loop at the end before closing curly bracket

```
$name .= ' ' . $rs2[i]['name'];
```

and after for loop

```
return $name
```

however it will be a good idea to use an array

Answer (score 2):

I believe,
`$name = $rs2[0]['name'];`

in your code should be
`$name .= $rs2[$i]['name'];`

And also if you want to return all the names at once in the end, you might want to concatenate them.

Answer (score 2):

You  should convert your `$name` variable to an array.
In that way you can push the new name read from MySQL to the array for every loop cycle and return the complete array with all values.

You should define `$name` before the for loop:

```
$name = array();
```

And in the loop, substitute `$name` assignment with:

```
array_push($name, $rs2[$i]['name']);
```

Pay attention to substitute the index 0 with the $i counter when retrieving names from the recordset.

Answer (score 1):

Change your code with in for loop `$name = $rs2[0]['name'];` as `$name = $rs2[$i]['name'];`

> Because, in your code point of view index always return `0th value`.
>
> So better to place index value as `i`

```
for($i=0;$i<$_REQUEST['countLoc'];$i++) {
    $val=$_REQUEST['val_check'.trim($i)];

    $sql="UPDATE customer SET sub_ID=$field_id WHERE ff_custID='$val'";
    $rs=parent::_executeQuery($sql);
    $rs = parent::getAll($rs);

    $sql2="SELECT * FROM customer WHERE sub_ID='$field_id' AND ff_custID='$val'";
    $rs2=parent::_executeQuery($sql2);
    $rs2=parent::getAll($rs2); 

    $name = $rs2[$i]['name'];
                  ^ Index value here
    echo $name;
}
```